# How to include Bootstrap icons in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Basically after a bunch of work I've finally managed to get up and running with Bootstrap in my ASP.NET MVC4 project.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Here is my bundleconfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css"));
         }
```

However when I try to add an HTML element with an icon:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

The icon does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last bundle needs to be a `StyleBundle`, not a `ScriptBundle`. Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                        "~/content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "~/content/css/font-awesome.min.css",
                        "~/content/css/common.css"));
```

I should note that I organize my CSS files into a specific folder, and this specific project uses [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in place of the Glyphicons.

**As noted from the comments**, the default Bootstrap package assumes that the CSS files are in one folder, and that the icon sprite file is in another folder at the same level as the CSS folder. Based on that assumption, the path to the sprite is set to `"../img/glyphicons-halflings.png"`. If your files are not located in the same places, you need to manually edit the path, or use the **[Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html)** to build a download that has the correct path for both the light and the dark versions of the sprite file.

Comment: Ahh I've changed it to ScriptBundle however the icon still doesn't show up.

Comment: If you open Firebug (or your browser's native dev tools), do you see a 404 error on the sprite file?

Comment: Okay, and what is the exact path that Bootstrap is trying to load the sprite file from?

Comment: It attempts to load from:
/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

NOT Content

Comment: Yeah, without a initial `.` that path will resolve from the site root. So either change it to `/content/img/glyphicons-halflings.png` or add the `.` at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry for sounding so dumb. But where do I change it to /content or add the dot?

Comment: If you're using the default download for version 2.3.2, it's on line 2285. Otherwise, do a search on `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]`, which is the selector that applies the background image. You'll also want to change the "inverse" path on the next set of selectors. The `..` you see there indicates that the browser should request the resource from one level above the CSS file's location, hence why it's resolving to be from the site root.

Comment: Alright thanks. I ended up just throwing the img folder into the root.
Thanks a lot for your help!